# Search on partial key

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with documents of the form:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56ec4e1bbf2f16a55f287d31"),
    "username" : "John Doe",
    "dates" : {
            "2014-12-24" : 25
    },
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56ec4e1bbf2f16a55f287b32"),
    "username" : "Jane Doe",
    "dates" : {
            "2014-12-27" : 92
    },
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56ec4e1bbf2f16a55f198d31"),
    "username" : "Harry Potter",
    "dates" : {
            "2014-01-31" : 25
    },
}
```

Is it possible to perform a partial query on `dates` such that I can get all records from December? For example, I can do `db.collection.find({"dates.2014-12-24":{$exists:1}})` and get the first document but is there any way to do something like `db.collection.find({"dates.2014-12-*":{$exists:1}})` and get both the first two documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to restructure the database such that values that are 
unknown are not keys.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56ec4e1bbf2f16a55f198d31"),
    "username" : "Harry Potter",
    "dates" : {
            "key":"2014-01-31",
            "value" : 25
    },
}
```

Now, you can use [regex](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) queries for your searches.