# mongodb query in childs not known

Tags: mongodb

I am working on mongodb.
I would like to be able to search in child nodes by ommitting one level.

Let's imagine the following document:

```
{
    "node1": {
        "node2": {
            "node3": "test"
        },
        "node2a": {
            "node3": "testa"
        },
        "node2b": {
            "node3": "test"
        },
        "node2c": {
            "node3": "test"
        },
        "node2d": {
            "node3": "testa"
        }
    }
}
```

If I want to have this document returns I can do:

```
{ "node1.node2a.node3" : "testa" }
```

The problem is that I will have to search in lot of documents which have different "node2" values as it is randomly generated. However node1 and node3 are known.

Now what I would like to know if it is possible to do:

```
{ "node1.WHATEVER.node3" : "testa" }
```

Is it feasible ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097315/search-on-partial-key

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51992488/mongoose-aggregation-match-based-on-enum-values/51992577#51992577

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using aggregagtion :  [addFields aggregation stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields) with [$objectToArray operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/), then match and remove added field.

```
db['01'].aggregate(
    [
        {
            $addFields: {
              "newNode1":{$objectToArray:"$node1"}
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
            "newNode1.v.node3":"testa"
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                newNode1:0
            }
        },
    ]
);
```

This will provide all documents that contains "testa" as node3 value.

$addFields with $objectToArray will result to the following structure, then $match and remove created field with $project.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b840cdf0b354c1b829a19fc"), 
    "node1" : {
        "node2" : {
            "node3" : "test"
        }, 
        "node2a" : {
            "node3" : "testa"
        }, 
        "node2b" : {
            "node3" : "test"
        }, 
        "node2c" : {
            "node3" : "test"
        }, 
        "node2d" : {
            "node3" : "testa"
        }
    }, 
    "newNode1" : [
        {
            "k" : "node2", 
            "v" : {
                "node3" : "test"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "node2a", 
            "v" : {
                "node3" : "testa"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "node2b", 
            "v" : {
                "node3" : "test"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "node2c", 
            "v" : {
                "node3" : "test"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "k" : "node2d", 
            "v" : {
                "node3" : "testa"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```